# Predicate to retrieve data

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, predicate

I have created a method using criteriaBuilder to return a specific data. Its successful when I run it but return an empty list. 
Below is the code

```
public List<WeekCycleEntity> searchOnWeekCycles(String keyword) {

EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<WeekCycleEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(WeekCycleEntity.class);



Root<WeekCycleEntity> weekCycleEntity = cq.from(WeekCycleEntity.class);


Predicate findName = cb.like(weekCycleEntity.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%");
Predicate findExecutedBy = cb.like(weekCycleEntity.get("executedBy"), "%" + keyword + "%");
cq.where(findName, findExecutedBy);



TypedQuery<weekCycleEntity> query = em.createQuery(cq);
return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: It means your criteria does not match any record.

Comment: i made sure that it has a match record before running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only reason could be case not matching so please try this

`cb.like(cb.lower(weekCycleEntity.get("name")), "%" + keyword.toLowerCase() + "%");`

Comment: Good to know. Ok please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks.